# Access type not working properly

Tags: google-api

Using the same permission and online access type for my app, I tested it for the first time the consent page requested for correct permission, which is **user email** and **user basic profile** access permission. However, the next time when I used Chrome incognito mode, the consent page now requested for **offline access**.

The url demonstrates my situation looks like this in Google playground:

**https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile**

Note: There is no **access_type=offline**

How do I keep the same access permission (user email and basic profile info) for the next time a returning user logs in using his Google account?